# How to add key listener to a view in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to add another action to the default refresh button (F5) in Eclipse.
I have to recognize if my view is selected and then to trigger some actions beside the existing ones for F5.

I actually tried the following:

```
     </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
      <key
            commandId="com.command5"
            schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"
            sequence="F5">
      </key>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <command
            defaultHandler="com.KeyHandler"
            id="com.command5"
            name="Trigger View ">
      </command>
   </extension>
```

The problem is that when I press F5 I have to choose between my command and the default refresh command. How can I do my actions beside the already existing ones when F5 button and these actions to be executed only if my view is selected ?

Answer (score 0):

You can "bind" a shortcut key such as F5 to a Command. You may do so in Eclipse -> Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys. In here you can customize your keys for different views. Hope you find this helpful.

Comment: I don't want to create a new scheme...I just want to add some operations to the already existing ones but only for one view and without the need of selecting what command to execute on a bind